# Using UnityEngine -- Unable to start resource

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got an error when "Using UnityEngine": unable to find resource.

It's like Visual Studio can't detect/load the UnityEngine library

I just installed Unity, created a new project in Visual Studio 2017 Community and added: 
`Using UnityEngine`

Can't open from Unity:
[Image from Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZdMf.png)

Can't select .cs files from Unity:
[Image from Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxHIz.png)

@Jack Mariani solved, thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the unity extension for visual studio?

Comment: In the Visual Studio Installer, I installed the Development with Unity toolkit, that's what you mean?

Comment: Yea have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: Yes, I already restarted also checked for Windows Updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you opened Visual Studio from itself, that might not connect it directly with unity assemblies.

Try these solutions:

- Try opening visual studio from unity: Assets/Open C# Project
  [image]
- Try creating a new monobehaviuour in unity (Right Click on inside "Project" window then Create/C# Script). Then double click on the new item
  [image]

Comment: Yea I just open Visual Studio or double click the ".sln" file

Comment: dobule click on the cs file from within unity, or do Assets Open C# project as suggested, Unity updates .sln under the hood

Comment: didn't work, please check my screenshots in the question

Comment: The screenshots you sent show that you were out of unity editor. I added images on the answer to show where those action can be done.

Comment: Just for editing a C# file I have to create a new 3d project?

Comment: If you already have a project, you can put the C# file on the unity project and open it from there. If you have no unity project you will need one.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is create the project from unity and in the editor add a script wich contains the essentials things to run.

I think you created a project in VS but is better if you create it via Unity becuase it have all the Unity libraries alredy installed

Comment: please check I updated the question adding screenshots for this

Comment: hmm, it's strange but in the first screen looks like you have to change the name, you can try to reintstall unity probably an error while downloading the unity hub or try to download another version